# Using a Function to clear TextViews and Set a Button to disable causes the app to crash

Tags: android, function, button, onclicklistener

As in the Title I have a function that clears a number of fields and sets a button to disabled. however when I click on the button the app crashes. I commented out the line calling the function in the switch and validated that the app does not crash anymore, deduction tells me that the issue is occurring within the function. I may be wrong. please see the code below:

```
final View calcbtn = findViewById(R.id.calcbtn);
final View clrbtn = findViewById(R.id.clrbtn);
final View abtbtn =  findViewById(R.id.abtbtn);
calcbtn.setOnClickListener((OnClickListener) this);
clrbtn.setOnClickListener((OnClickListener) this);
abtbtn.setOnClickListener((OnClickListener) this);
```

Those are the definitions above and where I link them to the screen elements. I believe that it is correct, because when I use the code like :

```
calcbtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.calcbtn);
```

I get an error about the item is not for Actvity Main. Setting all this I have gotten the calculate and the about button to work correctly, with the "implements OnClickListener" added to the extends Activity. 
Below I have the function that I believe is giving me the issue:

```
public void clrbtn (){
    billtotal.setText("");
    billtotal.requestFocus();
    numofpep.setText("");
    tv.setText("$0.00");
    calcbtn.setEnabled(false);
}
```

and the switch that calls the function. (It is the Second case item....)

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch(v.getId()){
        case R.id.calcbtn:
            calculate();
        break;
        case R.id.clrbtn:
            //clrbtn();
        break;
        case R.id.abtbtn:
           abtbtn();
        break;
    }
}
```

I am trying to make my code as tight as possible so that I can not only have a good app but also hone my coding technique to be as clean and as compliant as possible. Any and all assistance is appreciated. I am open to all suggestions.

A LogCat capture of the error:

```
12-17 15:26:16.395: D/gralloc_goldfish(10982): Emulator without GPU emulation detected.
12-17 15:26:29.825: D/AndroidRuntime(10982): Shutting down VM
12-17 15:26:29.825: W/dalvikvm(10982): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a71930)
12-17 15:26:29.864: E/AndroidRuntime(10982): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-17 15:26:29.864: E/AndroidRuntime(10982): java.lang.NullPointerException
12-17 15:26:29.864: E/AndroidRuntime(10982):    at com.vertygoeclypse.tipcalc.MainActivity.reset(MainActivity.java:146)
12-17 15:26:29.864: E/AndroidRuntime(10982):    at com.vertygoeclypse.tipcalc.MainActivity.onClick(MainActivity.java:162)
12-17 15:26:29.864: E/AndroidRuntime(10982):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4204)
12-17 15:26:29.864: E/AndroidRuntime(10982):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17355)
12-17 15:26:29.864: E/AndroidRuntime(10982):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
12-17 15:26:29.864: E/AndroidRuntime(10982):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
12-17 15:26:29.864: E/AndroidRuntime(10982):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
12-17 15:26:29.864: E/AndroidRuntime(10982):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
12-17 15:26:29.864: E/AndroidRuntime(10982):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-17 15:26:29.864: E/AndroidRuntime(10982):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
12-17 15:26:29.864: E/AndroidRuntime(10982):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
12-17 15:26:29.864: E/AndroidRuntime(10982):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
12-17 15:26:29.864: E/AndroidRuntime(10982):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
12-17 15:26:30.004: D/dalvikvm(10982): GC_CONCURRENT freed 113K, 9% free 2679K/2940K, paused 8ms+6ms, total 173ms
```

I see the Fatal Exception from the Null Pointer, however being new to the environment and trying to learn Not really certain where to look at from the logcat error.

Please find below the xml for the screen items:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/LinearLayout1"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background= "#DDFFDD" 
android:orientation="vertical"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >
<View
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height= "20dip"
            android:background= "#DDFFDD"
            android:layout_marginTop= "5dip"
            android:layout_marginBottom= "5dip" 
/>
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <RadioGroup
        android:id="@+id/radioGroup1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:checkedButton="@+id/rb0per">

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/rb0per"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:checked="true"
            android:text="@string/_0_tip" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/rb5per"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/_5_tip"  />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/rb10per"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/_10_tip"  />

 <TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView4"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="right"
    android:text="@string/tiplabel" />

    </RadioGroup>



    <TableLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="right" >
    <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
           android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="left" >

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/billtotal"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="100"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:hint="@string/bill_total"
            android:inputType="numberDecimal"
            android:textSize="28sp"
            android:cursorVisible="false" >

            <requestFocus />
        </EditText>
         </TableRow>
        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow2"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:gravity="right" >                
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/billtotlabel"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_weight="100"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/bill_total_label" 
                android:gravity="right"/>

        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow3"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:gravity="right" >

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/pertotal"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="100"
                android:gravity="right"
                android:hint="@string/no_of_people"
                android:inputType="number"
                android:textSize="28sp"
                android:cursorVisible="false"  />

        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow4"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:gravity="right" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/pertotalabel"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_weight="100"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/number_of_persons_label"
                android:gravity="right"/>

        </TableRow>

    </TableLayout>

</LinearLayout>


<View
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height= "20dip"
            android:background= "#DDFFDD"
            android:layout_marginTop= "5dip"
            android:layout_marginBottom= "5dip" 
/>


<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/calcbtn"
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_weight="33"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:text="@string/calculate_button_label" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/clrbtn"
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_weight="33"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/clear_button_label"
        android:textSize="15sp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/abtbtn"
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_weight="33"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:text="@string/about_button_label" />
</LinearLayout>
<View
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height= "10dip"
            android:background= "#DDFFDD"
            android:layout_marginTop= "5dip"
            android:layout_marginBottom= "5dip" 
/>
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/totalview"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:hint="@string/per_person_amount_label"
    android:text="@string/dollarvalue"
    android:textSize="28sp"
    android:textStyle="bold" />
<View
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height= "20dip"
            android:background= "#DDFFDD"
            android:layout_marginTop= "5dip"
            android:layout_marginBottom= "5dip" 
/>

<TextView
   android:id="@+id/textView6"
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:layout_gravity="center"
   android:gravity="center"
   android:text="@string/each_pays_label"
   android:textAlignment="center"
   android:textSize="28sp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

These are the definitions for the screen elements:

```
    // Linking the definitions with the on screen widgets
    final View calcbtn = findViewById(R.id.calcbtn);
    final View clrbtn = findViewById(R.id.clrbtn);
    final View abtbtn =  findViewById(R.id.abtbtn);
    calcbtn.setOnClickListener((OnClickListener) this);
    clrbtn.setOnClickListener((OnClickListener) this);
    abtbtn.setOnClickListener((OnClickListener) this);
    tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.totalview);
    numofpep = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.pertotal);
    billtotal = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.billtotal);
    tiprdogrp = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.radioGroup1);
```

I hope the formatting is ok.

Comment: First of all, post your log-cat, otherwise noone can help you. Second, this line `tv.setText("$0.00");`, where did you declare the `tv`? I think it might be null and causing NPE

Comment: Please also post your xml where you defined billtotal, numofpep, tv and your buttons, plus the code you're using to find billtotal etc, as you've shown for buttons (assuming it's in onCreate(), post onCreate() code)

Comment: Yeap you should provide and analyse the Exception from Logcat yourself. If I was about to shoot what that is:
abtbtn.setOnClickListener((OnClickListener) this); Looks very strange to me. I suppose you are doing it inside of a listener and there is some casting problem. When this code is inside of a listener - remove the casting (OnClickListener) but use YourActivityName.this instead.

Comment: Where are you setting any of those textviews? You're missing far too much code for this to be a helpful question.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up all I am going to try and provide all the requested portions, I edited the original and place them all.

Comment: A tip: you can reduce the names of your variables to a, b and c. Clearly as easy to read, to understand and to maintain as "clrbtn", "abtbtn" and "calcbtn"....

Comment: I believe that with Mark's guidance I figured it out. with the line 162 from the logcat showing that the issue was pointing to the reset function and line 146 which was the calcbtn.setEnabled(False); I simply took that line out. I am not certain of the reason for the issue, and would appreciate any assistance on this if possible so that I may understand the logic behind it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would seem that the answer was right in front of me, and with Mark's help I looked at the logcat output and determined that the following lines are where the error was occurring:

```
    12-17 15:26:29.864: E/AndroidRuntime(10982):    at com.vertygoeclypse.tipcalc.MainActivity.reset(MainActivity.java:146)
    12-17 15:26:29.864: E/AndroidRuntime(10982):    at com.vertygoeclypse.tipcalc.MainActivity.onClick(MainActivity.java:162)
```

That being said I investigated the 2 lines in question and line 162 is the call to the reset or clear function:

```
        case R.id.clrbtn:
    reset();
    break;
```

the line 146 is an item within the function:

```
    calcbtn.setEnabled(True);
```

once that line was removed the issue resolved itself and the app started to work as it should, I have tried to crash the app and so far it is stable. Thank you all for the assistance and the guidance. I hope this helps others, once I examine the logic I will edit this to place the reasoning behind the error, if anyone can help with the logic that would be great but the issue is now resolved.

thanks once more for the assistance all.